# How to select an entire DataGrid Table Row and delete it with a button click using WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I'm new to WPF can anyone explain me how to select a DataGrid Table Row and delete it with a button click using WPF in MVVM model.

I can remove the row by button click only by hard coding the value.

```
 HostSystemInformation info = (from sysinfo in systemInformation
                                     where sysinfo.Sno == 4 
                                     select sysinfo).First();
```

From above code i can delete only 4th row. I want solution to GET VALUE IN A VARIABLE WHEN I SELECT A ROW in datagrid table. I want to use that variable instead of hardcoded value 4.
This coding not done in code-behind, done in seperate ModalView file

I have copied my code below someone give a solution for this.

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding DeleteIp}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontFamily="Ebrima" FontSize="12" Width="61" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="right" VerticalAlignment="center"/>
<DataGrid  Name="datagridIpTable"  ItemsSource="{Binding SystemInformation}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" CanUserAddRows="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sno}"  Header="S.No" MinWidth="50" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding strIpAddr}" Header="System Name" MinWidth="240"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding strSystemName}" Header="IP Address" MinWidth="240"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding strStatus}" Header="Status" MinWidth="140" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ModalView.csFile

```
private DelegateCommand deleteIp;

public DelegateCommand DeleteIp
{
    get { return deleteIp; }
    set { deleteIp = value; }
}

private ObservableCollection<HostSystemInformation> systemInformation;

public ObservableCollection<HostSystemInformation> SystemInformation
{
    get { return systemInformation; }
    set { SetProperty(ref systemInformation, value); }
}

public UserBase_ViewModal()
{
    SystemInformation = new ObservableCollection<HostSystemInformation>();
    deleteIp = new DelegateCommand(DeleteSystemInformationInIpTable);
}

private void DeleteSystemInformationInIpTable()
{
    try
    {        
        if(systemInformation.Count>0)
        {
            int count=0;
            foreach (object eno in systemInformation)
            {
                HostSystemInformation info = (from sysinfo in systemInformation
                                     where sysinfo.Sno == 4 
                                     select sysinfo).First(); /*Here instead of 4th row i need to pass variable dynamically by pressing any row */
                systemInformation.Remove(info);
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public class HostSystemInformation
{
    public int Sno { get; set; }
    public string strIpAddr { get; set; }
    public string strSystemName { get; set; }
    public string strStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your kind Replies

I got a very easy solution from my friend. I posted it below.

For Selecting a Row in a DataGrid Table, a property is there  `SelectedItem ={Binding ItemSelect}`, It is not necessary to write a code-behind.

View:

```
<DataGrid Name="datagridIpTable"  ItemsSource="{Binding SystemInformation, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSystemInformation}" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Sno}"  Header="S.No" MinWidth="50" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding strSystemName}" Header="IP Address" MinWidth="240" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding strStatus}" Header="Status" MinWidth="140" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

ModalView:

```
    private HostSystemInformation selectedSystemInformation;
    public HostSystemInformation SelectedSystemInformation
    {
        get { return selectedSystemInformation; }
        set { SetProperty(ref selectedSystemInformation, value); }
    }


    public UserBase_ViewModal()
    {
        deleteIp = new DelegateCommand(DeleteSystemInformationInIpTable);
    }

    private void DeleteSystemInformationInIpTable()
    {
       SystemInformation.Remove(SelectedSystemInformation);
    }
```

Regards,

R.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

```
systeminformation.RemoveAt(datagridIpTable.SelectedIndex);
```

this will delete the item from the observable collection which is selected in the datagridview. (which is probably binded to that observable collection)

EDIT: In the class for WPF window which holds the datagrid, add

```
public static int index;
    private void datagrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        index = datagrid.SelectedIndex;
    }
```

You can then access the static variable index from anywhere to get the selected index in the datagrid like this. `WPFclassname.index`
Hope this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm not writting the code in code-behind I'm writting in seperate ModalView file so i can't access 'Name =datagridIpTable' in ModalView..

Comment: OH. then you can define a public static integer field in the WPF class.
double click on the datagrid and it will generate an event for selection changed. in that event assign the value of datagridIpTable.SelectedIndex to the static field.
you can then access the public field from the Modal class and remove the item from observable collection at that index.

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck how do i transfer value from code-behind to ModalView file.                                                  private void datagridIpTable_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int x = datagridIpTable.SelectedIndex;
        }

Comment: You are declaring an integer in the event. declare it outside the event method and as public (I have edited my answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you do MVVM you do **NOT** delete a DataGridRow. what you do is - delete/remove the bound item in your OberservableCollection in your Viewmodel.